# Assembly Reference loads in Release, but not in Debug, Visual Basic 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, assembly-references

I am not very experienced.  Just trying to make some changes to source code that someone else wrote.

I had to add a reference to a .dll to get it to work in "Release" mode.  However when I try to  get it to work in Debug, it does not work.  (assembly reference not loaded).

Help?

Comment: You need to describe what does not work means, are you getting errors if so what are they?

Comment: getting error that says the assembly reference is not loaded.  It is chillkat.dll

Comment: specifically: An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'ChilkatDotNet2, Version=9.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb5fc1fc52ef09bd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Chillkat dot net is a actually a mixed mode assembly and it's quiet possible that you need to have the appropriate c runtime as well. This exception and a way to fix this is documented [here](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/win32_Framework46.asp)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I get this error when the executable is x86 and the dll it's referencing is x64. Check your build configurations to make sure it's targeting the correct platform.

In VS2013 go to Build -> Configuration Manager. There should be a drop down in the top left of the new window which contains the different build modes. Compare Debug to Release.

Answer (score 0):

BadImageFormatException is one exception thrown from the execution engine when you are trying to load one assembly compiled for a specific platform in another platform.

**Example A**

```
- project A, compiled as X86
- project B, compiled as X86
- executable, compiled in X86
```

all work fine in x86 machine and x64 operating system

**Example B**

```
- project A, compiled as X86
- project B, compiled as X86
- executable, compiled in AnyCPU
```

all work fine in x86 operating system
this throw exception in x64 OS (executable is in AnyCPU so it's run on x64 engine, so can't load x86 dll's)

**Example C**

```
- project A, compiled as AnyCPU
- project B, compiled as x86
- executable, compiled in AnyCPU
```

all work fine in x86 operating system
this throw exception in x64 OS (executable is in AnyCPU so it's run on x64 engine, so can't load x86 dll's)

**Example D**

```
- project A, compiled as AnyCPU
- project B, compiled as x86
- executable, compiled in x86
```

all work fine in x86 operating system
all work fine in x64 operating system
the exe is compiled specifically for x86 platform, so also in x64 machine run under x86 mode.

**Conclusion**

Visual studio run projects in OS configuration, so in debug mode if you don't have a specific x86 configuration for starting project and try to execute an x86 referenced dll it will fail